# espcomm_sync failed when connecting ESP8266 (ESP-01)

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I'm new to the Arduino (I'm a developer but didn't have a chance to work with this kind of device before) and wanted to connect my ESP8266 to the Arduino Uno. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Getting-Started-With-the-ESP8266-ESP-01/) but I got errors:

```
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_memfailed
error: espcomm_upload_mem_failed
```

I tried running WiFiScan from the examples. I've installed SiLabsUSB Driver (I'm on macOS) and tried different solutions across the internet and I couldn't make it work.
There are screenshots of the settings.

[image]
[image]

Comment: that error usually means the ESP isn't in programming mode when you try to upload a compiled sketch to it

Comment: @JaromandaX so how to put in the programming mode?

Comment: Of course, I'm assuming you're trying to flash new firmware onto the ESP-01, if so, read the tutorial again - see step 19 in the tutorial you "followed"

Comment: @JaromandaX actually I didn't get to the 19th step as I couldn't get past step 2 but this flasher contains only .exe file and I'm on mac

Comment: That instructable is rubbish then. To flash the firmware, you need to ground GPIO 0, then power up (or reset) the ESP01 - then it's in flashing mode

Comment: you do something else like the instructable. you installed the esp8266 core into Arduino IDE and you try to upload a sketch. but you did not put the module into flashing mode.

Comment: the wire connections in the instructable will damage your esp. esp rx pin is not 5 V tolerant. you need a level shifter. the 3.3 V pin on Uno can supply only 50 mA. the esp8266 needs 170 mA for WiFi transmition

Comment: @Juraj - According to the data sheet the pins of most ESP **are** 5V tolerant, I think I remember they support 6.7v but please check, before you trust me.  (There is a post on here about it somewhere)

Comment: I checked http://espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf

Comment: I used different [scheme](https://www.geekstips.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ESP8266-WiFi-ESP-01-aansluiten-via-Arduino.jpg) to connect and when I connect the Arduino to the MacBook then it flashes blue LED but I still cannot select COM port and get `espcomm` errors

Comment: I connected GPIO 0 to GND and clicked Upload it started blinking blue light but still got espcomm warnings.

Comment: i see that when some settings are off, or if i have a module wired to GPIO1/3

Comment: @Juraj [The CEO of Espressif confirmed that the IO is 5V tolerant.](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1499045113679103/permalink/1731855033731442/?comment_id=1732364133680532) And an [older datasheet (bottom of p17)](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2471/0A-ESP8266__Datasheet__EN_v4.3.pdf) mentions over-voltage protection.

Comment: ok, so why doesn't it work for me?

Comment: `I connected GPIO 0 to GND and clicked Upload` ... no, connect GPIO0 to GND, **then reset or power cycle the ESP01**, only now is it in flash mode

Comment: @JaromandaX noob question but how can I reset it?

Comment: you could add a momentary switch between the reset pin and ground

Comment: @JaromandaX any other solution? I don't have a switch

Comment: as I said, power cycle (turn power off then on) while GPIO0 is held to ground